# Convert Text to columns in Excel using VBA for dynamic columns and Rows

Tags: excel, vba, text-to-column

I have a report wherein i need to do Text to columns for dynamic columns( columns are usually around 24-30 months). I have used the macro recording to currently perform text to columns only for fixed columns.

Expected result - I need help in getting the below macro code to perform text to columns for multiple columns dynamically

Sample report data layout

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 | Data 4 | Data 5 | Data 6 |
| Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 | Data 4 | Data 5 | Data 6 |
| Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3 | Data 4 | Data 5 | Data 6 |

Macro Code

```
Sub Txt2Columns()

Dim Wb1 As Workbook

Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dvaan\Desktop\final_report" & ".xlsx")

Columns("A:A").Select
Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
Columns("B:B").Select
Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
Columns("C:C").Select
Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
Columns("D:D").Select
Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
Columns("E:E").Select
Range("E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("E2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
Columns("F:F").Select
Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown)).TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True

Columns("A:F").AutoFit

Wb1.Save
Wb1.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Your sample data don't look like if they need a text-to-column ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a loop that continues until finding an empty column. The below loops `Until rng = ""`, where `rng` is A2, B2, C2 etc, but you may wish to change that depending on how you define what to loop.

```
Sub Txt2Columns_Answer()

Dim Wb1 As Workbook, rng as Range
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dvaan\Desktop\final_report" & ".xlsx")
Set rng = WB1.Sheets(1).Range("A2")

Do Until rng = ""
    Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).TextToColumns _
        Destination:=rng, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Tab:=True
    rng.EntireColumn.Autofit
    Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1)
Loop

Wb1.Save
Wb1.Close

End Sub
```

It's worth noting that in my tests of the above, the first iteration of the loop (texttocolumns on A2) overwrites other data in the columns it spreads to.